# Apache2 proxy fastcgi conditional rewrite with proxy pass match and cookie

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, mod-proxy-fcgi

I currently have two projects:

1. /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web/app_dev.php
2. /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf2.local/web/app_dev.php

Both have same repo but are set to two different branches.

I have vhost for first site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sf.local
    ServerAlias www.sf.local

    DocumentRoot /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9071/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web/$1

    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    <Directory /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options -MultiViews

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/piotrek/Vhosts/logs/sf.local-error.log
    CustomLog /home/piotrek/Vhosts/logs/sf.local-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I request http://sf.local/ everything works fine. But now I want to send people to /sf2.local/ when there is cookie with name `THEME` set. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} THEME=new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sf2project
```

How can I combine mod rewrite with fastcgi proxy to server one site when there is no cookie and other when there is cookie set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.

Vhost should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sf.local
    ServerAlias www.sf.local

    DocumentRoot /home/piotrek/Vhosts

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9071/home/piotrek/Vhosts/$1

    <Directory /home/piotrek/Vhosts>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On

            # rewrite if cookie is set to "new"
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} THEME=new [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sf2.local/web/$1 [QSA,L]

            # rewrite to old version
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sf.local/web/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # local rewrite to app_dev.php if file does not exists
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf2.local/web>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # local rewrite to app_dev.php if file does not exists
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/piotrek/Vhosts/logs/sf.local-error.log
    CustomLog /home/piotrek/Vhosts/logs/sf.local-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web/app_dev.php

```
<?php
setcookie("THEME", "new", time() + 3600);

die('OLD THEME');
```

/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf2.local/web/app_dev.php

```
<?php

die('NEW THEME');
```

Now, when I enter http://sf.local/ first time,

1. request is rewritten to `sf.local/web/app_dev.php`
2. `ProxyPassMatch`handles request to old theme directory `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9071/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web/app_dev.php`
3. cookie is set
4. `OLD THEME` is displayed

After refresh

1. request is rewritten to `sf2.local/web/app_dev.php`
2. `ProxyPassMatch` handles request to new theme directory `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9071/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf2.local/web/app_dev.php`
3. `NEW THEME` is displayed

Rewrites also works for other files like http://sf.local/robots.txt. Without cookie, it is rewritten to `/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf.local/web/robots.txt` and with cookie to `/home/piotrek/Vhosts/sf2.local/web/robots.txt`